# tor browser launches but can't load any pages

Tags: troubleshooting

The tor browser launches & loads fine, but when I attempt to load a page/site I get the following warning :

Secure Connection Failed

The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.

```
The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.
Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.
```

Learn more…

Comment: Magic 8-Ball says...Kaspersky Anti-Virus

Answer (score 0):

I had problem with accessing web pages when I started using Firefox, and Tor browser is based on the Firefox code base, and it turned out to be a certificate issue with AdGuard. After I reinstalled the AdGuard certificate Firefox is working fine.

[image]

So my recommendation to you is to look around for any extensions that might be installed, and any software outside of the Tor Browser that might interfere with the internet traffic (like AdGuard). And also as suggested above, try disabling your Anti-Virus software and see if it works without it.